# How to add single label per svg element?

Tags: svg, d3.js, label

I'm attempting to add a simple data label to [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305111)

```
svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .text(function(d) { return d[0] });
```

but it writes all the data in all labels which I think is because the graph is split over several individual svg-elements. How can I fix this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sPZ55/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already binding the data to the SVGs, so there's no need for you to bind it again to the `text` elements. `svg` is actually the selection of SVGs here, so all you have to do is

```
svg.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .text(function(d) { return d[0] });
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sPZ55/1/).